# New to pgfplots, add a label to a 3d point

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

Never used pgfplots before, so just starting.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize}}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=center,view={135}{30},xmin=0, xmax=4, ymin=0,ymax=5,zmin=0,zmax=6,
    xtick={0,...,4},ytick={0,...,4},ztick={0,...,5}]
\addplot3+[mark=none,blue,thick] coordinates {(0,0,5) (3,0,5) (3,4,5) (0,4,5) (0,0,5)};
\addplot3+[mark=none,blue,thick] coordinates {(0,0,0) (3,0,0) (3,4,0) (0,4,0) (0,0,0)};
\addplot3+[mark=none,blue,thick] coordinates {(0,0,0) (0,0,5)};
\addplot3+[mark=none,blue,thick] coordinates {(3,0,0) (3,0,5)};
\addplot3+[mark=none,blue,thick] coordinates {(3,4,0) (3,4,5)};
\addplot3+[mark=none,blue,thick] coordinates {(0,4,0) (0,4,5)};
\addplot3+[mark=*,red] coordinates {(3,4,5)};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Why do I have a dashed line connecting the points (0,4,0) and (0,4,5) in my image?

Second, how can I add a label $(3,4,5)$ to the point (3,4,5)?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Sorry, I've posted my code in an edit above.

Comment: Use `\addplot3` instead of `\addplot3+`. `\addplot3+` changes the styles of the plots by cycling through a style list. And you can use `\addplot3[mark=*,red,point meta=explicit symbolic,nodes near coords] 
coordinates {(3,4,5)[$(3,4,5)$]};` to add the coordinate labels.

Answer (score 2):

The problem of the dashed line originates from the fact that you are using `\addplot3+`, which cycles the plot styles through a list. You overwrite the color but not the line style. So you should just use `\addplot3` instead. Note also that you could reduce the number of plots (but doing this in the answer would defeat the purpose because if you have no list to cycle through the issue does not arise in the first place). The coordinate labels can be added via `nodes near coords`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize}}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=center,view={135}{30},xmin=0, xmax=4, ymin=0,ymax=5,zmin=0,zmax=6,
    xtick={0,...,4},ytick={0,...,4},ztick={0,...,5}]
\addplot3[mark=none,blue,thick] coordinates {(0,0,5) (3,0,5) (3,4,5) (0,4,5) (0,0,5)};
\addplot3[mark=none,blue,thick] coordinates {(0,0,0) (3,0,0) (3,4,0) (0,4,0) (0,0,0)};
\addplot3[mark=none,blue,thick] coordinates {(0,0,0) (0,0,5)};
\addplot3[mark=none,blue,thick] coordinates {(3,0,0) (3,0,5)};
\addplot3[mark=none,blue,thick] coordinates {(3,4,0) (3,4,5)};
\addplot3[mark=none,blue,thick] coordinates {(0,4,0) (0,4,5)};
\addplot3[mark=*,red,point meta=explicit symbolic,nodes near coords] 
coordinates {(3,4,5)[$(3,4,5)$]};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note also that there is a `cube` plot mark, and that, if the whole purpose is to draw this cube, you do not need `pgfplots`.